# Difference between ぐらい　and さえ

Tags: grammar

A 'fill the gap in the sentence' is as follows:
外国に行くときは、その国のお金（　）　知っておいたほうがいい・

where options include:
についてさえ、
についてぐらい

What's the difference between them here, and which one would be best?
I understand they both refer/emphasise a degree here, basically meaning 'at least', or 'in the very least'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case さえ and ぐらい express two opposite attitudes of the speaker toward knowing what is the currency used in the country you are visiting.

・さえ indicates learning about the currency is a "high-bar" or near-maximum accomplishment:

> When you are going to a foreign country, it is advisable to **even** know what currency is used in the country.

・ぐらい indicates a "low-bar" or near-minimum accomplishment:

> When you are going to a foreign country, it is advisable to **at least** know what currency is used in the country.

Considering that knowing what currency the country uses is among the first things you (should) learn while planning your vacation, the best choice would be  "についてぐらい".

Answer (score -2):

～について about ～

さえ even, so much as (negatively used)

ぐらい as much as, at the least (positively used)